# Why would a computed property return undefined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

*Note: The data used in the program which is causing me trouble comes from outside so I am sorry not be able to provide a fully working example. Please just let me know if something is missing, I am adding all information I beive to be relevant to understand the context*

My Vue instance has a `computed` property which is dependent on a AJAX call to bring in data. What it does is to turn these returned data (as it) into a Vue property (`allcases` below) to be reused in the HTML code.

The `computed` section from my Vue instance:

```
computed: {
        allcases: function() {
            console.log('getting all cases')
            var request = $.ajax({
                    (...) <- a working AJAX call here, please see below
                })
                .done(function(msg) {
                    console.log('found: ' + JSON.stringify(msg.hits.hits));
                    return msg.hits.hits;
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, msg) {
                    console.log('error posting incident: ' + msg);
                });
        }
    }
```

When running this I see on the console

```
found: {"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"AVxeaaE5n3UYRVv5wrrJ","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-05-31T14:09:22+02:00","lastname":"ert","firstname":"ertr"}},{"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"AVxjykjeqc2UmzuwNYsy","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-06-01T15:13:40+02:00","lastname":"hello2","firstname":null}},{"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"AVxjx3TKqc2UmzuwNYsw","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-06-01T15:10:34+02:00","lastname":"hello","firstname":"worldddd"}},{"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"AVxfOF-sRInTI31ZgCYt","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-06-01T15:12:20+02:00","lastname":"hello","firstname":"worldddd"}},{"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"new incident","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-06-01T15:12:41+02:00","lastname":"hello1","firstname":"ertert"}},{"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"AVxfN4wIRInTI31ZgCYs","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-05-31T17:54:54+02:00","lastname":null,"firstname":null}},{"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"AVxjol5dRInTI31ZgCmI","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-06-01T14:30:04+02:00","lastname":"hjkj","firstname":"hjkhjk"}},{"_index":"incidents","_type":"incidents","_id":"AVxjyKaFqc2UmzuwNYsx","_score":1,"_source":{"time":"2017-06-01T15:11:53+02:00","lastname":"hello","firstname":"world"}}]
```

so right before `return msg.hits.hits` the content of `msg` (and `msg.hits.hits`) is correct and the content is what I expected.

This example replicates [the basic one from the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

**`allcases` is however `undefined` when I run the script.**

I know this because

**-1-**

I am watching the Vue components in the Vue extension in Chrome[image]

**-2-**

The HTML file has the following code

```
<div id="currentcases">
  {{allcases}}
</div>
```

which, when observed in Dev Tools' Elements, is empty:

```
<div id="currentcases">
            
            </div>
```

I really have no idea what is wrong with this code.

Comment: because it's not returning anything

Comment: @thanksd surely `computed.allcases` would still resolve to the function itself?

Comment: @thanksd: sorry, I do not understand, could you please elaborate? `msg.hits.hits` is an Array, and this is what is returned

Comment: @NickA Nope, that's not how computed properties work. The function he defined for the computed property will run, but if it doesn't return anything, accessing the vue instance's `allcases` property will be `undefined`

Comment: `msg.hits.hits` is returned in your promise's `done` callback. It's not being returned in the scope of your computed property's method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `allcases` computed property is `undefined` because the method for that computed property is not returning a value. When you return a value in the `done` callback, that does not magically also get returned in the scope of your computed property method.

Unless you are expecting to fire an async call each time some dependant vue property changes, I wouldn't make this code a computed property.

I would make `allcases` a regular data property initially set to `null`:

```
data() {
  return {
    allcases: null,
  }
}
```

Then, I'd put your async call in a new method (say `fetchAllcases`). In this method you can directly set the `allcases` data property to `msg.hits.hits` in the `done` callback:

```
methods: {
  fetchAllcases() {
    let self = this;
    console.log('getting all cases')
    var request = $.ajax({
            (...) <- a working AJAX call here, please see below
        })
        .done(function(msg) {
            console.log('found: ' + JSON.stringify(msg.hits.hits));
            self.allcases = msg.hits.hits;
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, msg) {
            console.log('error posting incident: ' + msg);
        });
  }
}
```

Then, just fire this method once in the component's `mounted` lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
  this.fetchAllcases();
}
```

Comment: "...regular data property initially set to null" - setting the target store property with initial null value solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), calling `$.ajax` returns [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), and that is what you are saving in your `request` variable, not `msg.hits.hits`

to achieve what you are trying to do, consider using [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed)

Comment: He's not even returning the promise.

Comment: @RoyJ yes, but he's saving it in `request` so i assumed that's what he's consuming!

Comment: But he doesn't return the `request` variable (which wouldn't make sense anyways). That's why the value of the computed property is `undefined`.